# Does GPGPU with WebGL work on any current mobile GPUs?

Tags: javascript, three.js, glsl, webgl, gpgpu

I've put together a fairly barebones example with Three.js - http://jsfiddle.net/4kehk2xv/7/ not very exciting but simple. If GPGPU works a square of randomly placed red coloured points should show, otherwise they'll all be positioned at the origin. The devices I'm testing  on (Nexus 5 and iPad3) support the `OES_texture_float` extension and have `MAX_VERTEX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS` greater than 0. They don't support (as most mobile GPUs appear not to) the `OES_texture_float_linear` extension, but we should be able to get around that by using `NEAREST` filtering.

The error I'm coming across is below, Three.js also reports that `OES_texture_float_linear` isn't supported but this appears to be a check in the WebGLRenderer and not to do with the code I'm running.

`[.WebGLRenderingContext]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION : glDrawElements: framebuffer incomplete (check)`

Comment: Additional info: The Nexus 5 bugs out with the above error, but still at least renders all the points at the origin. The iPad 3 (iOS 8.1.3) doesn't report any errors and doesn't render anything - although it does appear to support `OES_texture_float_linear`, which the Nexus 5 definitely doesn't.